# Переменные MySQL и оператор IN

Tags: mysql

Как сделать так, чтобы оператор `IN` нормально воспринимал данные которые содержатся в переменной `@ids`?

```
SELECT @ids:= 63,62,12,243,237;
SELECT * FROM talbe_name WHERE id IN (@ids);
```

Comment: я протестировал такой код - он вполне работает и работает ожидаемо.

Что Вы понимаете под словами "нормально воспринимал"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Неужели вывод команды `SELECT @ids:= 63,62,12,243,237;` не навел на размышления и не вызвал желания вывести полученную переменную на экран?
И даже неработающий запрос не вызвал желания вывести переменную на экран?

При любых проблемах с кодом программист **обязан** проверять содержимое всех переменных.

Для текущей постановки задачи цифры надо заключить в кавычки, а `IN` заменить на `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Но скорее всего исходная задача решается вообще по-другому, а для этого надо знать, откуда она взялась, но это уже будет отдельный вопрос.

Comment: SELECT @ids='63,62,12,243,237', * FROM talbe_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, @ids);

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно!